# Running regex in a shell --> invalid option

Tags: regex, grep

I got this regex to check PHP scripts for PHP 7 incompatibility:

```
grep -rl "->\$.+\[.+\]\(.*\)" .
```

I tried running this with grep in a shell and got **invalid option -- '>'**. So I removed all the \ and escaped the - and the >.

```
grep -rl "\-\>$.+[.+](.*)" .
```

This went through, but is it also correct? Thanks for helping!

Comment: I updated my OP with the details

Comment: See http://rextester.com/LPQA92417